# Will pipe insulation stop condensation on an HVAC drain line?

Tags: hvac, insulation, ceiling, condensation

## ISSUE

A sweaty condensation drain line is dripping and causing mold in a ceiling panel:

[image]

The condensation drain pipe is lengthy and spans two rooms:

[image]

## QUESTION

[Is insulating the pipe an effective means to counter this drip / mold problem?](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-4-in-x-6-ft-Foam-Self-Seal-Pipe-Insulation-ORS07812/204760815) If you have successfully solved this problem please state this in your response and include details / context.  Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Isolating the pipe from moist air has been the common fix for decades.

Comment: Good.  I was contemplating re-routing (re-piping) but it would be easier to insulate, because new piping would require a hole through the building wall.

Comment: Make sure you seal the gap in the insulation.  If moist air can get in, you'll have condensation inside the insulation.

Comment: To seal the gap, I am interpreting that that the insulation's slit (gap) must be closed with tape?

Comment: Yes. Duct or packaging tape at work well. Some products are self-sealing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you live but in humid climates it is standard practice to insulate condensate drain lines for that very reason.

Comment: The site is in Florida

Comment: So just for kicks I looked up the dew point in Tampa. It is currently 69 degrees. Where I am right now the dew point is 42 degrees. The condensation coming off your coil is around 40 degrees and will warm up a little going down the line.  Anything below the dew point will likely condense. That is why where you live everyone insulates their condensate drain and where I live almost no one does.