# What type of tape is appropriate for pipe insulation?

Tags: insulation, pipe

As a follow-up to my [sweaty pipe discussion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/119876/will-pipe-insulation-stop-condensation-on-an-hvac-drain-line/119881#119881), what type of tape is appropriate for to properly seal up pipe polyethylene insulation (see photo in link)?  I would think that scotch tape or painter's tape is not a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think duct tape is the best to hold insulation in place with but I have also had really good luck with electrical tape on the foam insulation. (Disclaimer, I am an electrician so I use a lot of electrical tape).

Comment: Exactly the sort of experience I was seeking: I have plenty of electrical tape, so I'm inclined to go that route